# what is the difference between select and autocomplete in material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

First of all, I know the name of these two components suggests so many things by itself but my understanding is that they both almost do the same thing and I don't know what is the exact difference. for example with a normal select component we can implement something like this:

```
const data = [{id:"d1" , product:"TV",year:"2022"}
             ,{id:"d2" , product:"phone",year:"2021"}
             ,{id:"d3" , product:"tablet",year:"2022"}
             ,{id:"d4" , product:"laptop",year:"2019"}] 

const Items = data.map((item) => (
    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.year}>
      {item.year}
    </MenuItem>
  ));

<Select label="year">{Items}</Select>
```

and I think we can do the same with autocomplete like this:

```
const data = [{id:"d1" , product:"TV",year:"2022"}
             ,{id:"d2" , product:"phone",year:"2021"}
             ,{id:"d3" , product:"tablet",year:"2022"}
             ,{id:"d4" , product:"laptop",year:"2019"}]
 <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={data}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Year" />}
    />
```

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for the two components and reviewed the demos in the documentation?

Comment: @RyanCogswell yes I read the documentation but my question is that what is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: I'm just confused by the question. If you played with the demos, there are quite a lot of obvious differences. `Select` doesn't have any of the auto-complete functionality -- there is no input to type into in order to see matches like on the `Autocomplete`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell yes but there is no difference between these two sample codes in the matter of functionality. am I right?

Comment: Your `Autocomplete` example doesn't work at all since `Autocomplete` is expecting the options to have a `label` property. If you define `getOptionLabel` for the `Autocomplete`, then it will work. Here they are in a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-6jm1y?file=/demo.js.